# Can I use oauth token at client side?

Tags: oauth, gdata-api

can I use oauth token generated on server at client side ?
if yes . 
will it be secure to going like that ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure I understand the question. But, in general, if you have the application token and the user token, you can use it anywhere. For instance, my application has a mobile registration or an web site registration.

Regardless of which one you do, the tokens are shared and can be used from either client.

Comment: but is there no security issue on using them at client ?

Comment: If you store them on the client, yes. I set up a secure webservice that my client called from my web site to retrieve the tokens. That way it was never stored in the client code.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth 2.0 AccessToken can be used to access its resource in client side (or anywhere), until it expires. That is what [Client-side Applications](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html#clientside)  means to do.