# Passing OAuth token from device to server: poor form?

Tags: oauth, facebook-oauth

I want to do the reverse of what's described here: [Can I use oauth token at client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966849/can-i-use-oauth-token-at-client-side)

I'm building a service that performs Facebook Graph API lookups on hyperlinks. It so happens that the Facebook Graph API always requires an OAuth token to lookup anything.

Is there anything wrong with letting clients pass their OAuth token to my service, so that I can hit the Facebook Graph API on their behalf? (My connection with the client would be over HTTPS for this.)

Comment: Once you have the client login to your app, you already have their access token … so what’s the actual point of your question? Which server-side technique are you gonna use? Have you looked for SDKs, or even at the docs for (server-side) authentication?

Answer (score 2):

Google does not recommend that but there is mixed approach described [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow).

> To take advantage of all of the benefits of Google+ Sign-In you must
>   use a hybrid server-side flow where a user authorizes your app on the
>   client side using the JavaScript API client and you send a special
>   one-time authorization code to your server. Your server exchanges this
>   one-time-use code to acquire its own access and refresh tokens from
>   Google for the server to be able to make its own API calls, which can
>   be done while the user is offline. This one-time code flow has
>   security advantages over both a pure server-side flow and over sending
>   access tokens to your server.